# c# generic Enum class operations

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I'm trying to achieve the following goals: having a method that will get a generic Enum and check if that enum is from the Enums defined in the same class and having another method that is returning the int value of the successfully checked Enum.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyClass(){

    public enum MyValue{
        Value1,
        Value2,
        Value3,
    }

    public enum MyString{
        String1,
        String2,
        String3,
    }

    public void Usage(Enum something){
        if(IsRight(typeof(MyValue))){
            Console.WriteLine("something = " + GetInt(something));
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: something is not MyValue");
        }
        if(IsRight(typeof(MyString))){
            Console.WriteLine("something = " + GetInt(something));
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: something is not MyString");
        }
    }

    private bool IsRight(System.Type enumType){
        // THIS IS WRONG and I don't know how to do it...
        return enumType.IsAssignableFrom(MyClass);
    }

    private int GetInt(Enum enumeration){
        // is there a better way to do the int conversion?
        return (int)Convert.ChangeType(enumeration, typeof(int));
    }
}
```

Actually the GetInt method works but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do it. About the IsRight method I have no clues on how to do it. basically the problem is that I need to check if the passed enum value will be of any of the enumerations defined in the same class the method is to avoid that the user will pass me an enumeration that the class doesn't know.

Thank you very much  :-)

**EDIT**
I apologize because maybe the example is not very good. I know I could list all the Enum by using the is keyword, but because I will have lots of Enum defined in my class, a much better example for that function could be:

```
public class MyClass(){

    public enum MyValue{
        Value1,
        Value2,
        Value3,
    }

    public enum MyString{
        String1,
        String2,
        String3,
    }

    private List<string> m_cachedStrings = new List<string>();

    public void Usage(Enum something){
        CacheStrings(typeof(MyValue));
        CacheStrings(typeof(MyString));
    }

    private bool CacheStrings(System.Type enumType){

        // THIS IS WRONG and I don't know how to do it...
        if(!enumType.IsAssignableFrom(MyClass))
            return;

        foreach(var item in Enum.GetValues(enumType)){
            m_cachedStrings.Add(item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private bool IsRight(System.Type enumType){
    return enumType.DeclaringType == typeof(MyClass);
}
```